# How to play MID file in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Is it possible to play MIDI files on iOS?
This would be the [MIDI format file](http://www.mediafire.com/?9m2sq3836xkarna) I was trying to play back.

Which framework / library could be used to play MIDI files on iOS?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : use the CoreMIDI framework to read the file, and the Core Audio framework to make sound (you'll also need to add the AudioToolbox framework).

[Here's a tutorial on the subject](http://www.deluge.co/?q=midi-driven-animation-core-audio-objective-c)

Basically, you can use the MusicPlayer object found in the AudioToolbox framework to read your file, then use the MusicPlayer to play notes on an AUSampler Audio Unit.